# LUKS encryption Mint - only being asked to decrypt one of my two encrypted drives

Tags: linux-mint, encryption, luks, disk-encryption, crypttab

I've just finished setting up LUKS encryption on new install of Mint 18.3. I mainly followed the steps in [this guide](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=228836) (only doing the system #1 setup however as this is the sole OS on this system).

My setup has `/`, `/boot` and `swap` on my SSD, and `/home` on a HDD, so I've added in the extra steps to set up LUKS encryption both on:

1. A partition on my SSD that I created logical volumes for `swap` and `/`. I called this 'encrypted_ssd'.
2. A partition on my HDD that only holds `/home`. I called this 'encrypted_hdd'.

During install I also checked the box to encrypt /home, and I followed the post install steps to mount them all properly and set up both encrypted_ssd and encrpted_hdd in my crypttab.

As far as I can see, I've followed the same steps for the hdd and ssd encrypted partitions. However when I boot into my install, it only asks me for a password to decrypt 'encrypted_ssd'. Is there a reason why it's not asking me to decrypt my 'encrypted_hdd' partition? Does the fact that the passwords are the same, or that I chose to encrypt my `/home`during install make a difference here?

Is a way to check that my `/home` is encrypted or not?

Here's what my crypttab looks like (cryptswap1 was already in my crypttab before I added the other lines):

```
cryptswap1 UUID=b6b9ac2c-6bd8-4689-bc43-9ed53ec305c7 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
# <target name> <source device> <key file>  <options>
encrypted_ssd   /dev/nvme0n1p3  none        luks
encrypted_hdd   /dev/sda1       none        luks
```

My partition setup is:

```
On nvme0n1 (ssd)
p1: efi
p2: /boot
p3: encypted_ssd

On sda (hdd)
1: encrypyed_hdd
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I ended up being able to solve this myself. I tried playing around with having different passwords for `encrypted_ssd` and `encrypted_hdd`, as well as choosing to encrypt my home folder during install or not.

The home folder encryption made no difference either way, but once I set different passwords for `encrypted_ssd` and `encrypted_hdd`, Mint asked for both passwords upon boot as I wanted. I wouldn't have thought this would be the case, as from what I've seen the passwords just point to a key which should be different for each drive anyway.

The only other change I made was to change my default encryption from sha128 to sha512 for both drives, explicitly:

```
sudo cryptsetup --hash sha512 --key-size 512 luksFormat /dev/sda1
```